# Non-blocking thread of subprocess stdout.PIPE stream with a queue on Windows still hangs

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, pipe, stdout

I am trying to work with `subprocess` routine that spawns an interactive child process which expects user inputs. This process normally hangs immediately if I try to read its `stdout` stream directly.

I read through many solutions using `fcntl`, asynchronous operations, `pexpect` and file output and reading redirections. Although temporary log files should work, I don't want to go through that route as I would like to keep the process interactive within the Python interface. From all of those, threads seemed to be the most easiest and straightforward way (I could not get `pexpect` to work properly, although it seemed to be a good option, too).

Indeed, when I implemented the following code (stolen from [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python)):

```
import os
import subprocess as     sp
from   threading  import Thread
from   queue      import Queue, Empty

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        proc = sp.Popen(['app'], stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, encoding='utf8')
        out = NonBlockingStreamReader(proc.stdout)

        print(out.readline(1))

class NonBlockingStreamReader:
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.s = stream
        self.q = Queue()

        def populateQueue(stream, queue):
            while True:
                line = stream.readline()

                if line:
                    queue.put(line)
                else:
                    raise UnexpectedEndOfStream

        self.t = Thread(target = populateQueue, args = (self.s, self.q))
        self.t.daemon = True
        self.t.start()

    def readline(self, timeout = None):
        try:
            return self.q.get(block = timeout is not None, timeout = timeout)
        except Empty:
            return None

class UnexpectedEndOfStream(Exception):
    pass
```

everything worked, flawlessly. Well, the problem is -- it worked on Linux only, even though the solution should be Windows compatible.

When I try to run this implementation on Windows, the newly created thread hangs the moment it tries to execute `stream.readline()`, never gets to actually populate the queue and thus the output of `out.readline(1)` read from the main thread is `None`.

How can I make this work on Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python).

Comment: @jknotek that's literally what I wrote in the problem description. The problem is -- that solution does not work on Windows

Comment: I'm literally sorry about that, lol.